# Given m bricks of x inches and n bricks of y inches, create row of z inches using combination of the given bricks

Tags: c++, for-loop

Given `m` number of small bricks (each `x` inches long) and `n` big bricks (each `y` inches long), we want to create a row which is `z` inches long using a combination of small and big bricks. Write a program to verify whether it is possible to create such row of bricks or not.

Examples-

input: We have 4(m) small bricks each 3 inches(x) long and 3(n) big bricks each 4 inches(y) long. We need to create row which is 14(z) inches long.

output: Yes

input: We have 2(m) small bricks each 2 inches(x) long and 2(n) big bricks each 5 inches(y) long. We need to create row which is 6(z) inches long.

output: No (no combination of bricks will make wall which is 6 inches long).

This is a question I was asked during an interview process. I wrote the following code in C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ int m,x,n,y,z;
  int small=0, large=0, sum=0;
  cout<<"Enter values : ";
  cin>>m>>x>>n>>y>>z;
  int i=0,j=0,flag=0;
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {   small=small+x;
        for(j=0;j<=n;j++)
            {   large=large+y;
                sum=small+large;
                if(sum==z || sum==small || sum==large)
                {
                cout<<"\nYes. Combination Possible";
                flag=1;
                }
                else if(sum>z && large>z)
                break;  
            }
        large=0;
    }
if(flag==0)
cout<<"\nNo. Not possible";
return 0;
}
```

How to solve this problem with a single loop or perhaps without a loop even?

Note: Solution Mx+Ny=Z is not allowed. Any other alternate solution.

Comment: So, if you had to do this by hand, how would you do it?

Comment: I'll try to maybe solve that equation Mx+Ny=Z or try different combinations of brick randomly. But I need an optimized alternate solution from a programming perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int m;   // number of small bricks
   int x;   // length of small bricks
   int n;   // number of big bricks
   int y;   // length of big bricks
   int z,z1,flag=0,flag1=0,m1,n1;   // length of wall
    cin>>m;
    cin>>x;
    cin>>n;
    cin>>y;
    cin>>z;
    z1=z;
    m1=m;n1=n;
    while(z>=0&&m>=0){
        if(z%x==0){
            if(m>=z/x){
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(z%y==0){
            if(n>=z/y){
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        z=z-x;
        m--;
    }
    while(z1>=0&&n1>=0){
        if(z1%x==0){
            if(m1>=z1/x){
                flag1=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(z1%y==0){
            if(n1>=z1/y){
                flag1=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        z1=z1-y;
        n1--;
    }
    if(flag1==1 || flag==1){
        cout<<"Possble";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Not Possible";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are basically trying all the combinations, and you are not even stopping when you find one that works, you just keep trying them all. This can certainly be improved: I would either 1) `break;` when you set `flag = 1;`, then in the outer loop `if (flag == 1) break;`, so that you would break from both loops, or 2) use `goto` to jump to the end of the loop (but this is VERY risky during an interview, because you might find someone who hates `goto`...), or 3) directly `cout << "Yes" << endl; exit(0);`

Anyway, I think they wanted you to implement some [branch-and-bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) algorithm. For example, in your approach you try to start from the small ones, and then you try to add the long ones. Suppose that by taking `i` small ones you have already gone beyond `z`: does it make sense to also try taking 0, 1, 2, ..., `n` long bricks? You already know you've gone too far. If you started from `i=0, j=0` and increased as you did, and for a given `i` you have already gone beyond z, you are sure there is no solution, and you can just `cout << "No" << endl; exit(0);`. Or, suppose that for the current `i` you are not beyond `z`, then you get into the inner loop and start adding the long bricks. If at a certain point you go beyond `z`, does it make sense to try adding even more bricks? Clearly not, you'd better `break` from the inner loop and try again with one more small brick. In other words: whenever you are sure you have gone too far, stop. This would mean that for the current branch your lower bound is higher than the value you have to reach, that is, the branch must be discarded because it can't give you a solution. Then, either exit directly (if, as in the first case, you are sure no other branch can bring you to the solution) or go to the next branch.

You could also do the opposite: if, for the current value of `i`, you see that even by taking all `n` long bricks you don't reach `z`, it means that trying the inner loop is a waste of time, and you can, from the outer loop, `continue;` to the next iteration, where `i` is increased. But this would require a little math (it can be done `if (i*x + n*y < z)`) which, given the constraints you were given, might not be allowed. Anyway, this corresponds to checking that your upper bound isn't too low. If it is, skip this branch and go on.

I don't think there is a solution with a single loop. If you were forced to use a certain total amount of bricks, let's say 10, you could start from 10 small ones, check, and if you haven't reached `z` you could swap a small one with a long one, thus trying: 0 and 10, 1 and 9, 2 and 8, and so on until 10 and 0. That would be a single loop. But there's no way to know in advance the number of bricks you need. All the shortcuts I can think of require solving some equation like `Mx+Ny=Z`, which isn't accepted.

So I'd go for the branch and bound: instead of trying all the combinations, try to understand if you are wasting your time, and in that case move on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the approach:

Fill the entire row with big bricks, without going past the desired length `z`.
Now check if the remaining length is a multiple of the length of the small bricks.
If it is, and we have enough small bricks, we have an answer.
If not, remove one big brick (as long as there are big bricks left) and try adding small bricks again.
If the number of small bricks is insufficient to reach the desired length, you're done.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
   int m;   // number of small bricks
   int x;   // length of small bricks
   int n;   // number of big bricks
   int y;   // length of big bricks
   int z;   // length of wall

   cout << "Enter values : ";
   cin >> m >> x >> n >> y >> z;
   int flag = 0;

   for (int numBig = min(z / y, n); numBig >= 0; numBig--) {
      int sum = numBig * y;
      if ((z - sum) % x == 0) {
         int numSmall = (z - (numBig * y)) / x;
         if (numSmall <= m) {
            cout << "Yes. Combination Possible" << endl;
            flag = 1;
            break;
         } else {
            break;   // not enough small bricks
         }
      }
   }

   if (flag == 0)
      cout << "No. Not possible" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your task is in fact a matter of solving a [linear Diophantine equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation.html) of the form

`z = ax + by`

where additionally the unknowns `a`, `b` we are looking for are restricted by `a<=m` and `b<=n`.

You can do it by

1. computing the greatest common divisor of x and y, `d = GCD(x,y)`.
2. if `z` is not a multiple of `d`, there is no solution.
3. if `z` is divisible by `d`, compute `z' = z / d`, `x' = x / d` and `y' = y / d`.
4. Solve the modified equation `z' = a'x' + b'y'` for `a'` and `b'` using [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) (which is basically one loop and runs in O(log(max(z, x, y)) ).
5. Compute `a` and `b` by multiplying `a'` and `b'` by `z'`
6. Check if the solution satisfies the constraints `a<=m` and `b<=n`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is reducing to finding `a` and `b`  such that `z=ax+by`, while `a<=m` and `b<=n`. You can solve it using only one loop iterating on `a` and solving the equation `z=ax+by` for `b`, while checking the condition `b<=n`. That's all.

Comment: Yeah, I was specifically told not to use that method/equation z=ax+by. As it becomes very easy! Need another alternate solution.

Comment: Huh? Are we to find a best solution or the worst one here?

Comment: Best but an alternate solution.

Comment: There is NO alternate solution here. It is a mathematical representation of the problem. There is no other mathematical representation to it. The alternate solution would be to take the physical bricks and play with them.

Comment: There might be a solution without using the equation implicitly? Like the one I have written but with lesser complexity (single loop).